# php urlencode produces wrong output after rewriting

Tags: php, preg-replace, urlencode, php-5.6, preg-replace-callback

Currently on php5.6. It seems to be impossible to urlencode a match with preg_replace.

```
$message = preg_replace('#(https?:\/\/www.domain.nl)(.*)#si', 'https://www.affiliatedomain.com/cread.php?id=1234&amp;affid=12345&amp;clickref=me&amp;p=$1$2', $message, 1);
```

So I tried with preg_replace_callback.

```
$message = preg_replace_callback('#(https?:\/\/www.domain.nl)(.*)#Usi', function($matches) { return 'https://www.affiliatedomain.com/cread.php?id=1234&amp;affid=12345&amp;clickref=me&amp;p='.urlencode('[['.$matches[0].']]'); }, $message, 1);
```

This works partially, tried $matches[1].$matches[2] instead of $matches[0] as well.

I assume:

```
$matches[0] = everything matched
$matches[1] = https://www.domain.nl
$matches[2] = /internet
```

When I try to replace https://www.domain.nl/internet I want this to become the output:

```
https://www.affiliatedomain.com/cread.php?id=1234&amp;affid=12345&amp;clickref=me&amp;p=%5B%5Bhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.nl%2Finternet%5D%5D
```

But instead I get:

```
https://www.affiliatedomain.com/cread.php?id=1234&amp;affid=12345&amp;clickref=me&amp;p=%5B%5Bhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.nl%2F%5D%5Dinternet
```

No matter what I tried I can't figure it out. Researching several simular threads here, but to no avail. So lets hope the experts have a solution.

Comment: Note that `#(https?:\/\/www.domain.nl)(.*)#Usi'`  just matches with `https?:\/\/www.domain.nl`, the `(.*)` at the end is always empty. Why did you use `U`? Remove it.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, Removed (.*) and U modifier. The output is still the same with the wrong urlencoding. The U modifier was there because it was in an example I found here at stackoverflow.

Comment: It seems removing `U` [fixes the issue](https://3v4l.org/STlM4). The `'#https?:\/\/www\.domain\.nl.*#si'` seems to be enough.

Comment: Yes for just a plain link it is. But actually for the html code it goes wrong.
Pasted this in your fiddle, then you see the problem.
<a href="https://www.domain.nl/internet" target="_blank" title="https://www.domain.nl/internet">https://www.domain.nl/internet</a>

Comment: You should not parse HTML with regex. However, in this case, [this one](https://regex101.com/r/aCj7qi/1) might work. See [this demo](https://3v4l.org/QKTn5).

Comment: Yes this works, but the title and link text are also changed. Only the href should. We are making progress thanks to you! :)

Comment: Solved it by adding ,1
$message = preg_replace_callback('#https?:\/\/www\.domain\.nl(?:/[^\s"\'<>]*)?#i', function($matches) { 
    return 'https://www.affiliatedomain.com/cread.php?id=1234&amp;affid=12345&amp;clickref=me&amp;p=' . urlencode('[[' . $matches[0] . ']]'); 
}, $message, 1);

Big Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~\shref=[\'"]\Khttps?://www\.domain\.nl(?:/[^\s"\'<>]*)?~i'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aCj7qi/2)

**Details**

- `\s` - a whitespace
- `href=` - `href=`
- `['"]` - a `'` or `"`
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding alltext matched so far
- `https?://www\.domain\.nl` - `https://www.domain.nl` or `http://www.domain.nl`
- `(?:/[^\s"\'<>]*)?` - an optional sequence:

  - `/`  - a `/` char
  - `[^\s"\'<>]*` - 0 or more chars other than whitespace, `"`, `'`, `<`, `>`

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/8QoGI):

```
$message = '<a href="https://www.domain.nl/internet" target="_blank" title="https://www.domain.nl/internet">https://www.domain.nl/internet</a>';

$message = preg_replace_callback('~\shref=[\'"]\Khttps?://www\.domain\.nl(?:/[^\s"\'<>]*)?~i', function($matches) { 
    return 'https://www.affiliatedomain.com/cread.php?id=1234&amp;affid=12345&amp;clickref=me&amp;p=' . urlencode('[[' . $matches[0] . ']]'); 
}, $message);
echo $message; // => <a href="https://www.affiliatedomain.com/cread.php?id=1234&amp;affid=12345&amp;clickref=me&amp;p=%5B%5Bhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.nl%2Finternet%5D%5D" target="_blank" title="https://www.domain.nl/internet">https://www.domain.nl/internet</a>
```

You may specify to replace the first occurrence using `1` *limit* argument to `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$message = preg_replace_callback('~https?://www\.domain\.nl(?:/[^\s"\'<>]*)?~i', function($matches) { 
    return 'https://www.affiliatedomain.com/cread.php?id=1234&amp;affid=12345&amp;clickref=me&amp;p=' . urlencode('[[' . $matches[0] . ']]'); 
}, $message, 1);
```

Comment: Both solutions work! I will double check tomorrow with other urls and url formats to see if the regex is holding up.

Comment: Everything just works fine! I've been trying, searching for over a week. I've got a working answer within a day. Much appreciated.